# Redirect after login set to true in react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been working on the redirect bug for awhile now.
Use Case = When a user types in username and password and clicks login it would normally do a POST to the api for the validation check and if that validation check comes back at 200 then it would redirect to UserContent component. I had commented out the validation check for now just to test if the login will redirect to the UserConent, but it wont. No error given. The Route is even declared in the App.js. So UseHistory() should be able to access that route and push the user to the component.
What did I do wrong?

App.js

> ```
> import React, { useState } from 'react';
> import { Container, Nav, Navbar } from 'react-bootstrap';
> import { Link, Route, BrowserRouter as Router, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
> import ContactForm from './pages/contactPage';
> import Login from './pages/loginPage';
> import Footer from './components/footer';
> import HomePageContent from './components/homePageContent';
> import SignUpForm from './pages/signUpPage';
> import { curRentState } from './assets/pageTitles';
> import './components/App.css';
> import UserContent from './pages/userContent';
>
> function App() {
>   //eslint-disable-next-line
>   const [loggedIn, setLoggedIn] = useState(false);
>
>   //eslint-disable-next-line
>   const [currentState, setCurrentState] = useState({ ...curRentState });
>
>   return (
>     <Router>
>       <Container className='p-0' fluid={true}>
>         <Navbar className='border-bottom' bg='transparent' expand='lg'>
>           <Navbar.Brand>RecipeHub</Navbar.Brand>
>           <Navbar.Toggle className='border-0' aria-controls='navbar-toggle' />
>           <Navbar.Collapse id='navbar-toggle'>
>             <Nav className='ml-auto'>
>               <Link className='nav-link' to='/'>
>                 Home
>               </Link>
>               <Link className='nav-link' to='/contact'>
>                 Contact
>               </Link>
>               <Link className='nav-link' to='/signup'>
>                 Sign Up
>               </Link>
>               <Link className='nav-link' to='/login'>
>                 Login
>               </Link>
>               <Link className='nav-link' to='/userContent'>
>                 userContent
>               </Link>
>             </Nav>
>           </Navbar.Collapse>
>         </Navbar>
>         <Switch>
>           <Route
>             path='/'
>             exact
>             render={() => (
>               <HomePageContent
>                 title={currentState.home.title}
>                 text={currentState.home.text}
>               />
>             )}
>           />
>           <Route path='/contact' render={() => <ContactForm />} />
>           <Route
>             path='/signup'
>             render={() => <SignUpForm title={currentState.signup.title} />}
>           />
>           <Route
>             path='/login'
>             render={() => (
>               <Login
>                 title={currentState.login.title}
>                 setLoggedIn={setLoggedIn}
>                 loggedIn={loggedIn}
>               />
>             )}
>           />
>           <Route path='/userContent'>
>             <UserContent />
>           </Route>
>           <Route>
>             <h1>404 Not Found</h1>
>           </Route>
>         </Switch>
>         <Footer />
>       </Container>
>     </Router>
>   );
> }
>
> export default App;
> ```

Login.js

> ```
> import React, { useState } from 'react';
> import { Route, Switch, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
> import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
> import SignUpForm from './signUpPage';
> // import axios from 'axios';
> import UserContent from '../pages/userContent';
>
> export default function LoginOut({ loggedIn, setLoggedIn }) {
>   const history = useHistory();
>   if (loggedIn) {
>     setLoggedIn(false);
>   }
>   const initialData = { userName: '', password: '' };
>   const [formData, setFormData] = useState(initialData);
>
>   const handleChange = (event) => {
>     setFormData(() => {
>       return { ...formData, [event.target.name]: event.target.value };
>     });
>   };
>
>   const handleSubmit = (event) => {
>     //eslint-disable-next-line
>     const [userName, password] = formData;
>     event.preventDefault();
>     // if (userName && password !== '') {
>     //   axios
>     //     .post('http://localhost:5000/login', {
>     //       data: {
>     //         userName: userName,
>     //         password: password,
>     //       },
>     //     })
>     //     .then((response) => {
>     //       console.log(`statusCode: ${response.statusCode}`);
>     //       console.log(response);
>     //       if (response.statusCode !== 200) {
>     //         alert(response.statusCode);
>     //         setLoggedIn(false);
>     //         history.push('/signup');
>     //       } else {
>     //         setLoggedIn(true);
>     //         history.push('/userContent');
>     //       }
>     //     })
>     //     .catch((error) => {
>     //       console.error(error);
>     //     });
>     // }
>     setLoggedIn(true);
>     history.push('/userContent');
>   };
>
>   const handleDirect = (event) => {
>     event.preventDefault();
>     history.push('/signup');
>   };
>
>   return (
>     <Container
>       style={{
>         display: 'flex',
>         margin: 'auto',
>         width: 'auto',
>         padding: '10px',
>         justifyContent: 'center',
>       }}
>     >
>       <div
>         variant='outline-dark'
>         className='container w-50'
>         style={{
>           border: '2px solid blue',
>           padding: '5px',
>           boxShadow: '2px 2px grey',
>         }}
>       >
>         <div style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
>           <h2 className='page-title1'>Log In</h2>
>         </div>
>         <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
>           <div className='mb-3'>
>             <label
>               htmlFor='userName'
>               className='form-label'
>               style={{
>                 color: 'black',
>                 display: 'flex',
>                 justifyContent: 'center',
>               }}
>             >
>               Username:
>             </label>
>             <input
>               name='userName'
>               type='text'
>               className='form-control'
>               id='userName'
>               value={formData.userName}
>               onChange={handleChange}
>               required
>             />
>           </div>
>           <div className='mb-3'>
>             <label
>               htmlFor='password'
>               className='form-label'
>               style={{
>                 color: 'black',
>                 display: 'flex',
>                 justifyContent: 'center',
>               }}
>             >
>               Password:
>             </label>
>             <input
>               name='password'
>               type='password'
>               className='form-control'
>               id='password'
>               value={formData.password}
>               onChange={handleChange}
>               required
>             />
>           </div>
>           <button
>             type='submit'
>             className='btn btn-success'
>             style={{
>               display: 'flex',
>               justifyContent: 'center',
>               margin: '10px',
>             }}
>           >
>             Log In
>           </button>
>         </form>
>         <button
>           onClick={handleDirect}
>           type='submit'
>           className='btn btn-success'
>           style={{ display: 'flex', justifyContent: 'center', margin: '10px' }}
>         >
>           Sign Up Here!
>         </button>
>         <Switch>
>           <Route exact={true} path='/userContent'>
>             <UserContent />
>           </Route>
>           <Route exact={true} path='/signup'>
>             <SignUpForm />
>           </Route>
>         </Switch>
>       </div>
>     </Container>
>   );
> }
> ```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Commented out `setLoggedIn(true)` and the `useHistory()` works as indented.

Comment: This was the correct answer to my problem and not the one above.

Answer (score 0):

```
const { userName, password } = formData;
```

**
The formData is an object and you're destructuring it as an array. So it is making the userName and Password undefined.
Since that may not match any record in your database it may not return the status code 200 as you were expecting.
**

Comment: I was NOT asking about the POST request. This post was about **useHistory()**. If you took the time to actually read my post you would of understood this. My Answer is the correct one because I solved the problem. In 1 day I will be marking it as the correct answer.